# Why is a modal using angular-ui select being rendered with angular errors?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular-ui

I'm using the Angular select-ui module on a rails app.  I'm rendering a modal that most of the time renders correctly, but occasionally, it renders and looks like the below, there is some kind of error that i don't totally understand.

Notice the angular code being displayed as though there was a problem while the page was being rendered.

[image: https://cl.ly/image/2v2r0U2R3w3Y/Image%202015-01-01%20at%205.03.21%20PM.png]

the modal normally looks like,

[image: https://cl.ly/image/1x1S2C3g2o1L/Image%202015-01-01%20at%205.14.14%20PM.png]

Oddly, closing the modal and re-accessing it, without a roundtrip to the server will fix this problem, so maybe the problem is tied to the dom needing to be completely loaded?  As best as I can tell, even if the scope holding the tag data is empty, the form will still render without issue.

based on the html code,

```
  <div class='form-group'>
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Company</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <ui-select multiple ng-model="article.companies" ng-disabled="disabled">
        <ui-select-match placeholder="Tag with related Companies...">{{ $item.name || "something" }}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="company in allCompanies | filter: {'name': $select.search}" >
          <small>
            {{company.name}}
          </small>
        </ui-select-choices>
      </ui-select>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I have a specific controller controlling the showing of the modal,

```
controllers.controller('articleSubmitModal', ($scope, $modal) ->
  $scope.open = (size) ->
    modalInstance = $modal.open(
      templateUrl: 'ng-views/url_submit_modal.html'
      controller: 'articleSubmitCtrl'
      size: size
    )
)
```

And the controller populating data into the select fields,

```
controllers.controller('articleSubmitCtrl', ($scope, $modalInstance, Company, Interface, Article, Community, Cause) ->

  $scope.cancel = () ->
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');

  $scope.allCompanies = []
  Company.getAll().then (allCompanies) ->
    $scope.allCompanies = JSON.parse allCompanies

  $scope.allCommunities = []
  Community.getAll().then (allCommunities) ->
    $scope.allCommunities = JSON.parse allCommunities

  $scope.allCauses = []
  Cause.getAll().then (allCauses) ->
    $scope.allCauses = JSON.parse allCauses
```

which is backed by services that look like,

```
  .factory 'Company', ($q, $http) ->
    Company = 
      getAll: () ->
        $http
          method: 'get'
          url: '/api/companies'
        .then (response) ->
          response.data.list
    return Company

  .factory 'Community', ($q, $http) ->
    Community = 
      getAll: () ->
        $http
          method: 'get'
          url: '/api/communities'
        .then (response) ->
          response.data.list
    return Community

  .factory 'Cause', ($q, $http) ->
    Cause = 
      getAll: () ->
        $http
          method: 'get'
          url: '/api/causes'
        .then (response) ->
          response.data.list
    return Cause
```

the chrome errors being rendered when this bug occurs are below.  I'm not entirely certain how to look into this problem at a more granular level without digging into the angular select library, which i'd tend to avoid at this stage of the debugging process.  How might I proceed?

```
angular.js?body=1:4734 Error: [ui.select:transcluded] Expected 1 .ui-select-choices but got '0'.
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/select.js?body=1:187:14
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/select.js?body=1:1064:21
    at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:2721:15)
    at boundTranscludeFn (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:2799:20)
    at controllersBoundTransclude (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:3218:22)
    at link (http://localhost:3000/assets/select.js?body=1:1053:11)
    at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:3503:13)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:3203:15)
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:3344:15
    at processQueue (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:5829:29) <div class="ui-select-container ui-select-multiple ui-select-bootstrap dropdown form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope" ng-class="{open: $select.open}" multiple="multiple" ng-model="article.companies" ng-disabled="disabled">
angular.js?body=1:4734 Error: [ui.select:transcluded] Expected 1 .ui-select-choices but got '0'.
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/select.js?body=1:187:14
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/select.js?body=1:1064:21
    at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:2721:15)
    at boundTranscludeFn (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:2799:20)
    at controllersBoundTransclude (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:3218:22)
    at link (http://localhost:3000/assets/select.js?body=1:1053:11)
    at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:3503:13)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:3203:15)
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:3344:15
    at processQueue (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:5829:29) <div class="ui-select-container ui-select-multiple ui-select-bootstrap dropdown form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope" ng-class="{open: $select.open}" multiple="multiple" ng-model="article.communities">
angular.js?body=1:4734 Error: [ui.select:transcluded] Expected 1 .ui-select-choices but got '0'.
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/select.js?body=1:187:14
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/select.js?body=1:1064:21
    at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:2721:15)
    at boundTranscludeFn (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:2799:20)
    at controllersBoundTransclude (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:3218:22)
    at link (http://localhost:3000/assets/select.js?body=1:1053:11)
    at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:3503:13)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:3203:15)
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:3344:15
    at processQueue (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:5829:29) <div class="ui-select-container ui-select-multiple ui-select-bootstrap dropdown form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope" ng-class="{open: $select.open}" multiple="multiple" ng-model="article.causes">
angular.js?body=1:4734 TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined
    at Array.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/assets/select.js?body=1:857:44)
    at Object.ngModelWatch (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:8391:42)
    at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:6290:46)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:6389:28)
    at done (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:3889:28)
    at completeRequest (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:4016:9)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:3981:11)
angular.js?body=1:4734 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at ctrl.getPlaceholder (http://localhost:3000/assets/select.js?body=1:500:43)
    at $parseFunctionCall (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:5365:31)
    at Object.expressionInputWatch (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:5640:35)
    at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:6290:46)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:6389:28)
    at done (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:3889:28)
    at completeRequest (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:4016:9)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:3981:11)
angular.js?body=1:4734 TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined
    at Array.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/assets/select.js?body=1:857:44)
    at Object.ngModelWatch (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:8391:42)
    at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:6290:46)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:6389:28)
    at done (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:3889:28)
    at completeRequest (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:4016:9)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:3981:11)
angular.js?body=1:4734 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at ctrl.getPlaceholder (http://localhost:3000/assets/select.js?body=1:500:43)
    at $parseFunctionCall (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:5365:31)
    at Object.expressionInputWatch (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:5640:35)
    at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:6290:46)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:6389:28)
    at done (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:3889:28)
    at completeRequest (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:4016:9)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:3981:11)
angular.js?body=1:4734 TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined
    at Array.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/assets/select.js?body=1:857:44)
    at Object.ngModelWatch (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:8391:42)
    at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:6290:46)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:6389:28)
    at done (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:3889:28)
    at completeRequest (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:4016:9)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:3981:11)
9angular.js?body=1:4734 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at ctrl.getPlaceholder (http://localhost:3000/assets/select.js?body=1:500:43)
    at $parseFunctionCall (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:5365:31)
    at Object.expressionInputWatch (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:5640:35)
    at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:6290:46)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:6389:28)
    at done (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:3889:28)
    at completeRequest (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:4016:9)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:3981:11)
6angular.js?body=1:4734 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at ctrl.getPlaceholder (http://localhost:3000/assets/select.js?body=1:500:43)
    at $parseFunctionCall (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:5365:31)
    at Object.expressionInputWatch (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:5640:35)
    at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:6290:46)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:6389:28)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:8900:25)
    at HTMLDivElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.js?body=1:2641:98)
    at HTMLDivElement.elemData.handle (http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.js?body=1:2448:135)
```

Comment: John, I wonder if you ever found a solution to this problem?  I have very similar symptoms and am having a hell of a time finding out the underlying cause.

Comment: @JoshuaGevirtz actually, I think that the problem was tied to not including the templates correctly.  http://cl.ly/image/2u0J0n3z0q1Z i'm including an html page in my layout that has the templates, https://gist.github.com/jcdavison/4855896287df0a223835  because I think the select plugin is attempting to inject the html from these templates into the dom elements that have the selectui directive, and if the templates don't exist, select-ui isn't graceful about it.

Comment: looks like we got to very similar places.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue, except the problematic ui-select was not on a modal, but rather in a partial rendered by ui-router.  After a day of investigating, I found the cause of my problem.  I have no idea if it is at all related to the issue you had, but I thought I would post my findings here anyway, in case someone could benefit.

I was under the impression that I had to have the ui-select template files (*.tpl.html) served by my machine so that they could be accessed by ui-select XHRs.  To make sure ui-select knew the path from which I was serving the templates, I configured ui-select to point it in the right direction:

```
myModule.config(['uiSelectConfig', function(uiSelectConfig) {
    uiSelectConfig.theme = '/static/application/js/bootstrap';
}]);
```

I don't know if this was ever necessary.  What I do know, though, is that at some point I moved to the most recent ui-select version available (0.10.0), which, it turns out, includes its default templates at the bottom of select.js itself.  All I need is the default Bootstrap template, so I don't need to host any of the templates myself.

By setting the theme as I did above (and not removing this configuration when I changed ui-select versions), I must have created a race condition due to which, about 50% of the time, ui-select tried to proceed without actually having the templates in hand (i.e. the requests were pending).

Once I made the realization that 0.10.0 contains the appropriate templates, the fix was very simple: I just removed the single line of configuration for ui-select shown above.  Everything seems to be working swimmingly now.

Comment: I found your situation to be relevant too though I modified the select.js file to point to the theme 'select', http://cl.ly/image/0v1k2m33401O but ultimately, i think the problem was the lib not being able to load necessary templates.